# android tab : if content is set through intent,all get call,need to call one intent at a time

Tags: android, tabs

I have a tab Activity MainTab.class which extends ActivtyGroup. In this class I made 2 tabs and set their content using Intent.

```
  public class MainTab extends ActivityGroup {

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.tab);
     tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);        
     tabs.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());
     spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tab1");
     Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this,tab1.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
     spec.setContent(intent)
    // and so on......
```

My problem is when I call MainTab.class my both intent get triggered. I want to execute one intent at a time; after that if user taps on second tab then I would like to call another tab.

Actually I am making server interaction in both tabs - so my requirement is: when user click on tab then request should get fired to the server. However first tapped tab should get fired when I call MainTab.class.

Answer (score 0):

The ActivityGroup class is deprecated. You should be using [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) instead to do your tab achieve a tab like interface (here's an [example](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/)). Either way, just use a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) for your server code. The loader will only be run when the tab is shown.

Note: if you're targeting devices that are pre-honeycomb, you can still use fragments and loaders by using the [Android Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

Comment: Yea, that's why I mentioned the android support package. You'll need it if you're on 1.6